# ggplot cuts plot in half?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to plot a graph on ggplot, it looks like it's only processed 1/4 of the map, and has left out the remaining 3/4 on the right.

[image: Plot that I've made]

Here is the code I've used to plot the image.

```r
 ggplot(eu1) +
   geom_sf(aes(colour = conct), size=1, alpha = 0.4) +
   scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

DATA

```
    conct        coord
1 40.00016  c(509760,179380)
2 40.00018 c(509440,179480) 
3 40.00018 c(512720, 175240)
4 40.00044 c(504620, 175100)
```

I have a large dataframe with over 70,000 variables.

Even when I extend the x-axis, the data points are missing from it. Does anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Any chance you can `dput` (some of) your `eu1` data? Does the `eu1` data frame (is it really a data frame with 70,000 variables?) have a geometry aesthetic?

Comment: When ggplot does not plot anything and does not warn you that it has removed "missing values", than there are probably no values to plot. @Edward pointed out to `geom_sf` and its special aesthetic. Have a look at the documentation: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html   --  is `eu1` an `sf` object?